# Object Oriented Programming in modern Fortran including a member of function pointers

Tags: oop, fortran

Now I am training object-oriented programming in FORTRAN, and I would like to make a program using a "type" containing a function pointer like the code shown below. However, intel Fortran compiler (v18) showed compile errors, and said that the first argument in FUNCTION trig(self, x) should be same type with the defined type in type-bound procedure including a pass-bind attribution.

I'm not still familiar with "modern" fortran programming, so that I can not understand the meaning of this compile error. Would you be able to lend your expertise?

```
MODULE test_mod
!
    use iso_fortran_env, only: REAL32, REAL64
!
    implicit none
!
    private
!
    integer, parameter, private :: sp = REAL32
    integer, parameter, private :: dp = REAL64
!
    type, public :: t_obj
        private
        real( dp ) :: val = 1.0_dp
        procedure( trig ), pass( self ), pointer, public :: trigFunc => null( )
    contains
        private
        procedure, pass( self ), public :: setFunc
    end type t_obj
!
    ABSTRACT INTERFACE
        FUNCTION trig( self, x )
            class( t_obj )                      :: self
            real( kind( 1.0d0 ) ), intent( in ) :: x
            real( kind( 1.0d0 ) )               :: trig
        END FUNCTION trig
    END INTERFACE
!
CONTAINS
!
    FUNCTION cosFunc( self, x )
        implicit none
        class( t_obj ) :: self
        real( dp )     :: x
        real( dp )     :: cosFunc
        cosFunc = cos( x ) * self%val
    END FUNCTION cosFunc
!
    FUNCTION sinFunc( self, x )
        implicit none
        class( t_obj ) :: self
        real( dp )     :: x
        real( dp )     :: sinFunc
        sinFunc = sin( x ) * self%val
    END FUNCTION sinFunc
!
    SUBROUTINE setFunc( self, i )
        implicit none
        class( t_obj ), intent( inout ) :: self
        integer :: i
        if( i .eq. 1 ) then
            self%trigFunc => cosFunc
        else
            self%trigFunc => sinFunc
        end if
    END SUBROUTINE setFunc
!
END MODULE test_mod
!
PROGRAM test_main
!
    use test_mod
!
    implicit none
    type( t_obj )         :: obj
    real( kind( 1.0d0 ) ) :: pihalf = datan( 1.0d0 ) * 2.0d0
!
    call obj%setFunc( 1 )
    write(*,*) obj%trigFunc( pihalf )
    call obj%setFunc( 0 )
    write(*,*) obj%trigFunc( pihalf )
!
END PROGRAM test_main
```

Comment: Please show the exact error from the compiler (and location).  At the very least, though, you need an [`import`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8751195/3157076) statement

Comment: @kachigusa: The hint of francescalus solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling your code with INTEL Fortran gives me this error message

> error #8262: For a type-bound procedure that has the PASS binding attribute, the first dummy argument must have the same declared type as the type being defined.   [SELF]

related to your function `trig( self, x )` in the abstract interface.

As mentioned by  **francescalus**, the `import` statement is missing in your function.

Adding it will solve your issue:

```
    ABSTRACT INTERFACE
        FUNCTION trig( self, x )
            import
            class( t_obj )                      :: self
            real( kind( 1.0d0 ) ), intent( in ) :: x
            real( kind( 1.0d0 ) )               :: trig
        END FUNCTION trig
    END INTERFACE
```

Please read also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751750/9222996).

Hope it helps?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for my delayed response, but I really thank you for your kindful comments and testing. Actually, the error message I obtained are same with the one shown by you. Since I didn't know the import statement, your advice is quite useful, and I could resolve my problem. Thank you very much.